# Chrome for Android: <ul> list-style not working

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with lists in chrome for android.
"Normal" browsers show a svg as bullet Point, but in Chrome for Android nothing is visible (checked with my mobile).

```css
li.hzlist {list-style: url(../../images/herz.svg) outside none!important;display: list-item;margin-left: 2em!important;-webkit-margin-left:2em!important;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="hzlist">test</li>
<li class="hzlist">test 2</li>
</ul>
```

If I insert the CSS inline, everything is working. But with external CSS it is not working.

Following the Problem URL: [svg bullet Points not working in Chrome for Android](https://www.stylebutton.de/hochzeit-buttons)
The lists are at the end of the document.
Has anybody an idea to solve the Problem?

Comment: The location of the image should be relative to the path of the css file. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: thanks, path ist ok. meanwhile the first li shows the bullet Point. I inserted the css in the head, so it works. Not the best solution, but better than nothing ...